# Calculating Riemann Sums

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Problem is above. In b-a/n b is 4, a is 2 and n is apparently 4, given that we know that t delta is .5 from the graph. I've evaluated the given equation into a table of values and my equation was .5(.44+.69+1+1.36+1.77)= 1.745. I've looked at a few Riemann sum videos. Not sure where I'm going wrong. 
[image]

Comment: It looks as if the left sum was calculated correctly. Your expression has the extra term $1.77$ but you did not use it. It would be used in the right sum, with $0.44$ discarded.

Comment: Maybe they are upset about your rounding. The left sum is exactly $1.75$.

Comment: That fixed my problem, @AndréNicolas. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left Riemann sum is equal to
$$0.5\left(\frac{2^2}{9}+\frac{2.5^2}{9}+\frac{3^2}{9}+\frac{3.5^2}{9}       \right).$$

This is exactly $1.75$. Perhaps the computer got upset with your $1.745$. Computers are sensitive.

For the right Riemann sum, discard the $\frac{2^2}{9}$ term above, and add the term $\frac{4^2}{9}$.

**Remark:** Maybe you calculated the values on your calculator, *wrote down* the rounded values, and added up. If that is the case, it would be a good idea to learn to use the *memory* feature of the calculator.